# HTML in an R / shiny app - how to reference (link/script/href) files on the server (javascript/html/css) within HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

When using `includeHTML()` in R/shiny, how do I reference other files on the server from within the included html page?

For example if I want to `<script>` an external javascript file,  `<link>` a css, or have a `<href>` link to a local html file.

By default other files in the shiny project directory don't seem to be visible from the html page that was included using `includeHTML()`